# Use fibers/future for async callback client side

Tags: meteor

I have a similar code:

```
Template.mytemplate.pippo = function() {
    var returnValue;
    asyncFunc(function (dataReturned) {
        returnValue = dataReturned;
    });

    return returnValue;
}
```

I have try to load future on client side

```
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
```

but don't work :(

How can I wait that *asyncFunc* return callBack finish to return template value *returnValue*

thanks!

Comment: On the client you would have to use asynchronous code. There isn't a way really past this. Maybe give the code on what exactly you want to do and perhaps you can use a Session variable to handle making the return reactive

Comment: Node Fibers is written in C++ and cannot be used in the browser. You might want to look into ES6 generators and the yield keyword, but you will not be able to use them in the majority of browsers.

Comment: Understand...The code I would use is that above (in the main post). Do you suggest to insert a Session.Set in callback of asyncFunc and made another template helper that check Session...is it right?

Comment: have you found a way to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of a question of where you should be calling `asyncFunc`, but once you figure that out, your code should look something like this:

```js
asyncFunc(function (dataReturned) {
    Session.set('returnValue', dataReturned);
});

...

Session.setDefault('returnValue', "loading..");   // or some other default that is safe
Template.mytemplate.pippo = function() {
    return Session.get('returnValue');
}
```